# How do I access a single agent from a population that was passed into a function?

Tags: anylogic

I created an agent type “Component” that contains parameters and variables. I then created a population of agents of this type “components[...]”. I have a function “addChartData()” that uses a for loop to act on individual agent variables from that population “components[i].hopperLevel”.

The function works fine if I call the agent directly however, when I add an argument to the function “addChartData(AgentArrayList comp) and try to pass the agent population to it, I’m unable to act on the variables (for example,  comp[0].hopperLevel and comp.get[0].hopperLevel aren’t valid). What’s the right syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic trick is:

```
((Component)comp.get(0)).hopperLevel
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Felipe.